# Python multiprocessing pool.map hangs after sklearn function call

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to perform some computation between a 2D array and a collection of 2D arrays using `multiprocessing`. Suppose I have a matrix, `mat1`, and a collection of matricies, `test`, in which I would like to compute all matrix multiplications between `mat1` and the elements of `test`. I am using multiprocessing to run the computations in parallel since the size of `test` is very large. However, I noticed that even for a small `test`, the computation never completes. Specifically, the program seems to never finish a matrix multiplication computation. It seems that a call to a particular `sklearn` function is causing the issue. I wrote the following code to illustrate this (I use `partial` rather than `starmap` because I would like to use `imap` and `tqdm` at a later point in time):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial
import numpy as np
import sklearn as sklearn

def bar(y, x):

    # this does not seem to complete
    mul = x @ y.T

    # so this does not print
    print('done')

    return mul

def foo():

    mat1 = np.ones((1000000, 14))
    test = (np.ones((1,14)), np.ones((1,14)))

    # these will finish
    print(mat1 @ test[0].T)
    print(mat1 @ test[1].T)

    with Pool(6) as pool:
        result = pool.map(partial(bar, x=mat1), test
        p.close()
        p.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Causes the hang
    sklearn.metrics.pairwise.rbf_kernel(np.ones((9000, 14)), 
                                        np.ones((9000, 14)))

    foo()
```

***NOTE:*** For those unfamilar with `partial`, this is from the documentation:

> functools.partial(func[,*args][, **keywords])
>
> Return a new partial
>   object which when called will behave like func called with the
>   positional arguments args and keyword arguments keywords.

I am forced to stop execution manually, otherwise it will run forever. Am I not using `multiprocessing` correctly?

For those interested, the full traceback after force stopping can be found below:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-18-6c073b574e37> in <module>
      8     
      9     sklearn.metrics.pairwise.rbf_kernel(np.ones((9000, 14)), np.ones((9000, 14)))
---> 10     foo()
     11 

<ipython-input-17-d183fc19ae3c> in foo()
     11     with Pool(6) as pool:
     12     # this will not finish
---> 13         result = pool.map(partial(bar, x=mat1), test)
     14         p.close()
     15         p.join()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py in map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
    266         in a list that is returned.
    267         '''
--> 268         return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
    269 
    270     def starmap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    649 
    650     def get(self, timeout=None):
--> 651         self.wait(timeout)
    652         if not self.ready():
    653             raise TimeoutError

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py in wait(self, timeout)
    646 
    647     def wait(self, timeout=None):
--> 648         self._event.wait(timeout)
    649 
    650     def get(self, timeout=None):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py in wait(self, timeout)
    550             signaled = self._flag
    551             if not signaled:
--> 552                 signaled = self._cond.wait(timeout)
    553             return signaled
    554 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py in wait(self, timeout)
    294         try:    # restore state no matter what (e.g., KeyboardInterrupt)
    295             if timeout is None:
--> 296                 waiter.acquire()
    297                 gotit = True
    298             else:

KeyboardInterrupt:
```

UPDATE 1:

After more debugging, I have discovered something peculiar. After implementing [sokato](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10500953/sokato)'s code, I managed to fix this example. However, I can trigger the issue again when calling the following `sklearn` function right before `foo()` in `main()`:

```
sklearn.metrics.pairwise.rbf_kernel(np.ones((9000, 14)), np.ones((9000, 14)))
```

I have updated the original post to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the multiprocessing pool. e.g

```
def bar(y, x):

    # this does not seem to complete
    mul = x @ y.T

    # so this does not print
    print('done')

    return mul

def foo():

    mat1 = np.ones((1000000, 14))
    test = (np.ones((1,14)), np.ones((1,14)))

    with Pool(5) as p:
    # this will not finish
        result = p.map(partial(bar, x=mat1), test)
        p.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    foo()
```

To fit your exact syntax you can do it like

```
    pool = Pool(6)
    result = pool.map(partial(bar, x=mat1), test)
    pool.close()
```

If you are interested to learn more, I encourage you to check out the documentation. https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.pool.Pool

Comment: Your code managed to fix the original issue. Thanks! Unfortunately, I found a situation in which the problem arises again. I have update the post and added additional information at the bottom. Do you have any additional information as to why this new issue arose?

Comment: my call to `rbf_kernel()` finishes execution but then causes `foo()` to never complete.

Comment: I would suggest maybe opening a new question with the same level of detail as the first and linking it to this comment feed as the original question has been answered. This will give me an idea of what the new issue is exactly and the errors associated with it without clouding this solution.

Comment: I have taken a closer look and realized that my update did not solve your problem. I removed it. I will see if I figure out the issue.

Comment: It is quite strange but I think it is something system dependent. I ran the code on one of my laptops and found a limit of 586 if i set this to be the first dimension of the sklearn arrays and mat1. On another system I have I found a limit of 1171. These values cause it to hang.  Otherwise it runs almost instantly.